# If a row in a RREF Matrix is [0 0 : 1], does that mean there is no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to determine if a polynomial can be written as a linear combination of two other polynomials. Using a graphing calculator, one of the rows in RREF came out to [0 0 : 1]. Does that mean the polynomial can't be written as a linear combination? Is there no solution?

Comment: Read the row as an equation using the entries in the row as the coefficients... that would say that $0x + 0y = 1$.  Is it possible for $0x + 0y = 1$?  No.

Comment: "*Using a graphing calculator, ...*"  Be careful not to become too overly reliant on calculators and computers.  You need to learn how to think for yourself for a lot of this.